# Open pdf in Books

Tags: ipad, pdf, books

I used to use Books on my iPad but transferring files now seems difficult.
Attempting to sync with a Mac seems to delete files.

I can AirDrop to Files but seem unable to open/transfer to my Books library.
Is this possible?

Comment: Is this question about sync problem or about how to transfer pdf file to Books?

Comment: Which iPadOS? Is it up to date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can read, you succeeded in getting the .PDF files on your ipad.
You can import them to Apple books by doing the following.

1. Locating the file in files
2. Long pressing it
3. Press share
4. Scroll over in the list with icons and press ... More
5. Scroll down and press books.

Now the pdf file will be added to your books library under PDFs

If this did not solve your issue, or this is not the issue you are having, please reformulate your question!